# "Sehr geehrte oder geehrter" for companies or institutes

Tags: word-choice, gender

Normally we use `sehr geehrte/geehrter` for addressing the persons according to gender.
How can we address a `company/department/institute` in a professional email?

Comment: I just fixed some typos and grammar. Welcome to Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren

because as you noticed it's hard to target your salutation towards one person when you're writing to a company or group. This phrase roughly translates to the English expression

> To whom it may concern

Comment: please explain why...

Comment: @Vogel612 Explain why "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" is used? It is, by yeras of experience. - Or explain why it translates to "To whom it may concern"? Well, I'm not sure, I tend to write "Dear sir or madam" (notably singular), but I'm not a native speaker of English

Comment: Your translation... if I am not mistaken, *"to whom it may concern"* is gravely wrong in this context. At least for me that sounds like *"to whoever cares (because i do not)"* and that would be plain wrong.

Comment: @Vogel612: "to whom it may concern" is a common salutation for letters in English...

Answer (score 0):

Recently, also generic descriptions can be found. In advertisement letters, you are adressed as

> Sehr geehrter (Neu)-Kunde,

if the style of conversation is deliberately casual, you can adress a company by

> Sehr geehrtes Firma-XYZ-Team,

But bear in mind, that you should always use personal names if possible.